# Open connection generate Error: 0x80040e21 - Microsoft OLE DB Service Components: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB

Tags: sql-server

I have simple ancient ASP site, Global.asa contains only open connection, there are no copy operation like in SSIS packages, this is ONLY first open connection for SQL 2022 in Global.asa

```
Sub Session_OnStart() 
...
cnn.Open DSN_Name
```

Full Error

```
Unhandled exception at line 134, column 2 in http://localhost:80/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/global.asa
0x80040e21 - Microsoft OLE DB Service Components: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
```

[SessionStart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G0sa.png)

My ODBC Source

```
 Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 18.02.0001
 Data Source Name: XXXXXXXXX
 Data Source Description: 
 Server: Localhost
 Use Integrated Security: No
 Database: XXXXXXXXXX
 Language: (Default)
 Data Encryption: Optional
 Trust Server Certificate: Yes
 Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
 Mirror Server: 
 Translate Character Data: Yes
 Log Long Running Queries: Yes
 Query Log File: F:\TMP2\XXXXXXXX-QUERY.LOG
 Query Log Time: 30000
 Log Driver Statistics: Yes
 Statistics File: F:\TMP2\XXXXXXXXX-STATS.LOG
 Use Regional Settings: No
 Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
 Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes
 Use FMTONLY: Yes
```

My SQL Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021522) - 16.0.1050.5 (X64)   Jan 23 2023 17:02:42   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 22621: )
```

What does it mean? What reason of this error?

Comment: The ODBC Source details mentioned don't seem related to the connection string details shown in the screen shot's hover tip. Have you read through [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) yet to see if there's anything missing from your connection string?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I don't see anything special tuning in this acticles. All parameters is standard, point of discussion about SSL=yes/no and about implementation to Unix and improvement Azure implementation. This is not interesting for me, because I have simple ASP application for Windows. Also SSL can define in ODBC layer, there are 3 options, I try any of it. I don't see in this discussion any useful information. Except... I can ask question about my issue in that topic, but MS usually delete any question what can not feet to it win.